# ceilf and floorf equivalent methods for NSDecimalNumber

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsdecimalnumber

Are there equivalent methods for ceilf and floorf for the NSDecimalNumber type? I couldn't seem to find any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple solution: You can get the float value of the number object and call `ceilf()` or `floorf()`:

```
ceilf([decimalNumber floatValue]);
```

Otherwise, you can use the `– decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:` method.

First you'll need to implement the `NSDecimalNumberBehaviors` protocol for each rounding mode you want to use:

```
@interface DecimalRounder : NSObject <NSDecimalNumberBehaviors> { }
@end

@implementation DecimalRounder

- (NSRoundingMode)roundingMode {
    return NSRoundUp;
}

- (short)scale {
    return 0;
}

@end
```

And then (assuming your decimal number is 12.5):

```
DecimalRounder *rounder = [[DecimalRounder alloc] init];
NSDecimalNumber *decimalNumber = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithFloat:12.5];
NSDecimalNumber *roundedNumber = [decimalNumber decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:rounder];
NSLog(@"decimalNumber: %@", decimalNumber);
NSLog(@"roundedNumber: %@", roundedNumber);
```

You'll get:

```
decimalNumber: 12.5
roundedNumber: 13
```

Comment: I went with the second option because the conversion to float (or double) loses precision.